# Bitnami Subversion Set-Up On Google Cloud

Tags: svn, locking, google-compute-engine, bitnami

I have the Compute Engine instance running, can log in via SSH (instructions for that could be a little more verbose IMHO), have even got to the point of doing an SVN add, but I am getting the following:

Import E:\tmp\xxxx_SVN to https://13x.21x.18x.18x/subversion
Can't open file '/opt/bitnami/repository/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied

Maybe another way to ask this - what is the proper way to import an existing SVN database to the Bitnami SVN server?

I used the 'preconfiged' set-up - I assumed all services were/are running and I didn't necessarily have to perform any svnadmin tasks on the server VM instance.

Thanks,
John W.

PS - I really want to get this working with svn+ssh vs. https - haven't found a good write-up on that just yet - any pointers to a procedure that isn't part of an infinite e-mail thread appreciated.

Comment: $ sudo chown -R daemon:subversion /opt/bitnami/repository

This seemed to fix - at least I am able to import now.  Makes one wonder why the preconfiged image isn't really complete.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

Just in case anyone has this problem in the future. In order to use svn server from a local machine via ssh, you'll have to do some configuration changes because by default the example repository is set to be used by subversion server (that's why the repository owner is subversion).

When you try to access using ssh, you are accessing as bitnami user so I'll recomend you to run

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:bitnami /opt/bitnami/repository
```

Instead of daemon.